# Slideshow play automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slideshow with script identical to, [How to make slideshow auto-play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234943/how-to-make-slideshow-auto-play) , but can't seem to make mine work. Any suggestions to what it is? This slideshow does have a parent element, could that be the cause, or maybe css?

My links as requested: I'm positive that it's the correct file path, as my controls still work.

```
<!--get jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--project slideshow scripts-->
<script src="profile-javascript/project-slideshow.js">
</script>
<script src="profile-javascript/project-slideshow2.js">
</script>
```

HTML:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

setInterval(function() {
  plusSlides(1);
}, 1000);
```

```css
/*courosel section starts*/

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 7.5em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 7.5px auto;
}

.mySlides,
.mySlides2 {
  display: none;
}

.project-text {
  color: ;
  display: flex;
  position: ;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
}

.slideshow-img {
  width: 17.4rem;
  height: 10.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -webkit-transition: display 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.slide-hover-p {
  display: none;
}

.slideshow-img:hover+.slide-hover-p {
  display: block;
}

.fade-car {
  -moz-animation-name: fade-car;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade-car;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

.project-text a,
a:visited,
{}

.previous,
.nexxt {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: ;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  transition: 0.85s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.nexxt {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.previous:hover,
.nexxt:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#p-others:hover,
#n-others:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #00004d;
}

#p-coding:hover,
#n-coding:hover {
  background-color: #00004d;
  color: white;
}


/*courosel media queries*/

@-webkit-keyframes fade-car {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade-car {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .previous,
  .nexxt,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<!--slider starts-->
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade-car">
    <div class="project-text">
      <img src="images/colorado_view2.jpg" class="slideshow-img img-fluid" alt="global6" />
      <p class="slide-hover-p"><i>(My Profile Webpage)</i></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade-car">
    <div class="project-text">
      <img src="images/global (35).jpg" class="slideshow-img img-fluid" alt="global6" />
      <p class="slide-hover-p"><i>(My Profile Webpage)</i></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade-car">
    <div class="project-text">
      <img src="images/global (35).jpg" class="slideshow-img img-fluid" alt="global6" />
      <p class="slide-hover-p"><i>(My Profile Webpage)</i></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="p-others" class="previous" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a id="n-others" class="nexxt" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<!--slideshow ends-->
```

Comment: please add a link

Comment: @LSolorio you don't have a class in your html called 'dot'  (so you can't get them by classname) Also the example you cited uses jquery, you would have to add that to your code in your head

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with the help of @RachelGallen by adding the missing elements with the "dot" class. Thanks! Also, sorry, I'm a noob with stackoverflow editing. I don't know why the code is showing like that.

```
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>                             <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>                             <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
```